# Javascript error saying that I do not provide an API token

Tags: javascript, api

Can someone take a look at the code below.
I try to make a converter work, which makes a png from a jpg.
I keep getting this error:
{"message":"Please provide an API key or token."}

This is the code:

```
const {
file,
filename,
mimetype,
token,
size,
folderid,
} = inputs;
 
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("x-oc-api-key", "API KEY");
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
 
var raw = {
 type: 'remote',
 source: file}
 conversion: {
 target: 'png'}
 
var requestOptions = {
 method: 'POST',
 headers: myHeaders,
 body: raw,
 redirect: 'follow'
};
 
 
 const {url} = inputs;
try {
 const response = await fetch("www.apiwebsite.com/jobs", requestOptions);
 const outputvariableurl = await response.json();
 return { outputvariableurl }
} catch (err) {
 const error = {
   code: 'unknownError',
   message: 'Something went wrong.',
   rawError: err,
 } 
 return [1, { error }]
}
```

Comment: `myHeaders.append("x-oc-api-key", "API KEY");` - I assume you are actually using a real API key here?

Comment: Not related to the API key, but `body: raw` with `raw` being a plain object is incorrect. It should be `body: JSON.stringify(raw)` (since you've said you're sending JSON).

Comment: @Kinglish yes, I put an actual key there